# Stargazer only outputs the header of table

Tags: r, stargazer

I was just trying to create a table with stargazer to show some descriptive statistics of my variables, but stargazer only outputs the header of the table. I also tried type = "html", but I get the same problem. I'm not sure what the issue is here, can anyone help me out?

[image]

```
structure(list(ADPT_1 = c(4, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3), ADPT_2 = c(4, 
4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4), ADPT_3 = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 
2, 2), RE_1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5), RE_2 = c(4, 4, 
2, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4), RE_3 = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 
5), RE_4 = c(3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4), COMP_1 = c(3, 3, 
1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3), COMP_2 = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 2, 
3), COMP_3 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3), PLEX_1 = c(4, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3), PLEX_2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 
2), PLEX_3 = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2), ORG_1 = c(4, 4, 
2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4), ORG_2 = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
3), ORG_3 = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3), TOP_1 = c(4, 4, 
1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4), TOP_2 = c(4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 
4), TOP_3 = c(4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5), PRES_1 = c(2, 2, 
1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5), PRES_2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 
3), PRES_3 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4), REG_1 = c(3, 3, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3), REG_2 = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
3), REG_3 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask].

Comment: @Peter I added some data now, sorry

Comment: Could you also include the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://a.web.umkc.edu/andersonbri/Lab19Jan2017IntroToR.html) suggests that you need to use `as.matrix()`:

```
stargazer(as.matrix(psych::describe(x)),type="text")
```

(I used `type="text"` to get something easier to cut-and-paste here)

```
===================================================================================
       vars n  mean   sd   median trimmed  mad  min max range  skew  kurtosis  se  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADPT_1  1   10 3.400 1.350   4     3.500  1.483  1   5    4   -0.420  -1.358  0.427
ADPT_2  2   10 3.200 1.549   4     3.250  1.483  1   5    4   -0.297  -1.722  0.490
ADPT_3  3   10 2.900 1.524 2.500   2.875  2.224  1   5    4   0.149   -1.705  0.482
RE_1    4   10 3.800 0.919   4     3.875  0.741  2   5    3   -0.433  -0.830  0.291
RE_2    5   10 3.800 1.033   4     3.875    0    2   5    3   -0.741  -0.789  0.327
RE_3    6   10   4   1.054   4     4.125  1.483  2   5    3   -0.512  -1.218  0.333
RE_4    7   10 3.600 0.966 3.500   3.625  0.741  2   5    3   0.080   -1.297  0.306
COMP_1  8   10 2.500 1.269   3     2.375  0.741  1   5    4   0.293   -0.896  0.401
COMP_2  9   10 3.500 1.269   4     3.625  1.483  1   5    4   -0.587  -0.896  0.401
COMP_3  10  10 3.300 0.949 3.500   3.500  0.741  1   4    3   -1.237  0.607   0.300
PLEX_1  11  10 2.900 1.101   3     2.875  0.741  1   5    4   0.171   -0.596  0.348
PLEX_2  12  10 3.300 1.160   4     3.250  0.741  2   5    3   -0.139  -1.839  0.367
PLEX_3  13  10 2.700 0.949 2.500   2.500  0.741  2   5    3   1.237   0.607   0.300
ORG_1   14  10 3.900 0.876   4       4      0    2   5    3   -0.733  -0.173  0.277
ORG_2   15  10 3.100 1.197   3     3.125  1.483  1   5    4   -0.168  -1.181  0.379
ORG_3   16  10 2.400 1.265   3     2.375  1.483  1   4    3   -0.095  -1.867  0.400
TOP_1   17  10 3.200 1.398   4     3.250  0.741  1   5    4   -0.535  -1.393  0.442
TOP_2   18  10 3.400 1.350   4     3.500  1.483  1   5    4   -0.420  -1.358  0.427
TOP_3   19  10 3.600 1.174   4     3.750  1.483  1   5    4   -0.772  -0.162  0.371
PRES_1  20  10 2.500 1.434   2     2.375  0.741  1   5    4   0.814   -0.903  0.453
PRES_2  21  10 2.900 1.101   3     2.875  0.741  1   5    4   0.171   -0.596  0.348
PRES_3  22  10 2.500 1.269   2     2.375  1.483  1   5    4   0.587   -0.896  0.401
REG_1   23  10 2.700 0.949   3     2.750  1.483  1   4    3   -0.169  -1.171  0.300
REG_2   24  10 2.600 0.516   3     2.625    0    2   3    1   -0.349  -2.055  0.163
REG_3   25  10 3.100 0.994   3       3    1.483  2   5    3   0.439   -1.084  0.314
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```